# How do I calculate the interest on my deposits to my landlord?

Tags: calculation, interest, rent

I was renting from this company called harbor house builders.  I started renting from them in 2009 and at that time I was renting an apartment at 650 a month so I put 650 for rent and 650 for deposit.

Almost a year later I changed houses with the same company and transferred my deposit to the new house (which cost more) so I put the extra down for that deposit which was 950 and I stayed in that house for a year.

I again transferred to another house (same company) and again put down the extra owed on my deposit which was 1,100.

What I want to know is: in all that time I rented from this company how much interest was accrued? So I know exactly what I'm owed?

Comment: I believe the laws regarding interest on your deposit are a state matter. You might wish to larify your country, and locale.

Comment: Some states or localities (counties or cities) specify the minimum rate at which the landlord must pay interest on the security deposit, while some do not. In the latter case, the interest rate, if any, will be specified in the lease(s) that you signed. So, unless you tell us what the interest rates are, and what are the exact dates involved, it is difficult to say anything.  "almost a year later" does not help.

Comment: In Australia, the landlord or their agent does not hold the deposit (we call it the Bond). It is lodged with a state government agency called The Rental Bond Board (part of Fair Trading). So any interest is paid by them to the tenant when the lease ends.

Answer (score 3):

Some states/cities even have a handbook for tenants regarding landlord-tenant law. It will discuss the purpose of deposits, how long the deposit must be held before interest is required, and the rates.

In Virginia, the rates are not specified in the contract, because they are based on specific bond rates which can vary over the life on the lease. Th handbook explains how the find the rate, and how it is to be calculated.

In your case because separate properties are involved the period might not be as easily calculated. They might be one management company, with different owners of each property. They might even have different companies with similar names running portions of their properties.